# Oracle is dropping my table before select statement finishes

Tags: sql, oracle

At work we have a large Oracle SQL query designed to output two select statements based off of analysis and table combining in prior scripts. At the end of these select statements we truncate the temp tables that were created. My issue is that the tables are getting truncated before the select statement has time to run, resulting in 0 output for both queries and empty tables that now need the whole process to be run over again to populate the tables correctly. This is something I'm trying to help automate but I'm stuck on how to get Oracle to wait for the select statement to finish processing before triggering the truncate. Very simply it looks like:

```
Select * from temp; 
Truncate Table temp; 
commit;
```

Comment: That looks strange. TRUNCATE - as far as I can tell - waits until previous command is finished, so there's no way it would truncate TEMP table before SELECT returns the result. Therefore, either you did something wrong, or your "very simple" code doesn't really look like that. Besides, there's no need to COMMIT. TRUNCATE is a DDL, it will implicitly commit.

Comment: You will show us the complete code.

Comment: Alas, this question is unanswerable without more details.

Comment: The code doesn't look how I've written it, I wasn't sure how to anonymize it without spending a lot of time editing out table and column names but it's a basic select statement followed by the truncate statement as followed. Everytime I've selected the whole query and ran it, the output is blank, but when I select everything except the truncate part of the query, I get back the results. Not sure why the bossman decided to add the commit either..

Comment: Missing semicolon perhaps? Obviously not in this example, but maybe in your code? Perhaps you commented out a piece of code and the semicolon was in it?

Comment: @NicoleGagne APC is right, we need more details. How is the code being executed? At a command line, in a GUI, via JDBC in a java app? You said 'both queries' - but your code only shows one.

Comment: Nicole, the database executes the SQL statement as they arrive, and even if the TRUNCATE arrives before the SELECT finishes, it will wait, as it needs exclusive lock on the table, being a DDL. So, we need a bit more details to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE` is a DDL sentence in Oracle which means it can modify the structure of tables and databases, instead of using `TRUNCATE` why don't you try to change it for a simple `DELETE` which is a simple DML sentence in Oracle that just change the data.

Comment: Why? Because there's a LOT of data involved, so deleting will take *ages* to complete, use a lot of undo and stuff? Who knows (except Nicole).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can only ne the case if the 2 select statements (one followed by a truncate) are running in separate sessions. Run in the same session and the problem would be solved although you *may* lose out on a performance benefit of runnng them in parallel.